# cross-validating a multiple time-series dataset with mixed-effect model

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, mixed-models

I'm looking at the relationship of school district expenditure on the crime rate of cities/towns within that school district, specifically from 2000 to 2017. There's roughly 14,000 school districts. Crime data is the dv; there are a host of covariates: per capita inc., pop density, pop, etc. etc. Total I have 90,000 observations (I'm limited by cities/towns reporting crime to the FBI)

I have a multi-level mixed-effect model and am trying to cross validate with training/test datasets.

I've searched on-line. Have tried using caret and other methods. No dice. I find a package that works well with time-series, it doesn't work with mixed-effect models (Read through postings by Rob Hyndman and forecasting, and this was the case: would handle time-series, but not mixed-effects)

I can write code for regular cross-validation/k-fold, but I've really met my limits here.

Comment: Have you looked into `brms`. Depending on the time series methods you are using it would be easy to have a time series with hierarchical features. Then in Bayesian framework you could pretty easily do leave one out cross validation .

Comment: No, I haven't. I know a bit of Bayesian inference; can you point me to a resource where it discusses hierarchical features?

Comment: Here is one thread <https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/more-advice-on-a-multilevel-time-series-model-in-brms/4344> which considers an autogressive structure with hierarchical components. Additionally any of the info at <https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/> or the vignettes at <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html> are excellent places to start